# How to see message MQTT properties when using mosquitto_sub command

Tags: mosquitto, libmosquitto

I'm running Mosquitto command `mosquitto_sub` to subscribe to a topic and see the messages published there.

I would like to be able to see the **MQTT properties** used when someone publishes a message in that topic.

Is there any way?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the [documentation for `mosquitto_sub`](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html)?

Comment: Yes, I read it but I didn't understand the -D flag. I want to see all the MQTT properties, not sure why I have to define properties when I'm a subscriber.

Comment: I would pay more attention to output format and protocol version.

Comment: This looks like more like a graphic adventure hint rather than a Stack overflow answer.

Comment: That would be why it’s a comment. See, you got it! I’m happy to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the format option (`-F`) that takes a pattern, for example:

```
mosquitto_sub -t <topic> -V mqttv5 -F %C
```

In the example above we are printing the Content type property (`%C`).

Don't forget the version option (`-V`) using `mqttv5`.

You can find more printable properties here: https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html#outputformat (see MQTT related parameters)